# Cursor Subquery DB2

Tags: sql, db2, cursor, subquery

I am trying to create a stored procedure that returns a data set, using a cursor, that contains multiple sub-queries. The query works when executed as a standalone script, but when putting it into the stored procedure format using a cursor it doesn't work. Specifically it seems as though only a single row of the subquery has the outer query running against it.

```
SELECT 
    contract.province,
    contract.contract_date
WHERE contract.CON_CONTRACT_DATE >='2015-01-01' 
AND contract.CON_CONTRACT_DATE < '2018-11-01'
```

Returns:

```
Province |  Contract Date
---------------------------
Ontario  |  June 11th, 2017
Quebec   |  July 12th, 2017
```

Then I nest that query into the following:

```
DECLARE C2 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
SELECT 
    province
    FROM (
       SELECT 
          contract.province,
          contract.contract_date
       WHERE contract.CON_CONTRACT_DATE >='2015-01-01' 
       AND contract.CON_CONTRACT_DATE < '2018-11-01'
    );
```

What I should be getting is:

```
Province | 
---------
Ontario  |
Quebec   |
```

But I'm only getting:

```
Province | 
---------
Ontario  |
```

My actual query is much more complicated than this, I realize you wouldn't have a sub-query to give you something the main query would give (already obtained province, why would you need to query it again), but this is the general issue I'm getting albeit very simplified.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you missing FETCH statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the result of the following?
I added 'WITH HOLD' clause to the cursor declaration, since this may help in case your tool you use to call the SP runs in autocommit mode and issues some other queries during the result set processing. These queries would implicitly close the cursor. You may comment out this clause to check if the result differs.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

create or replace procedure test
dynamic result sets 1
begin
  DECLARE C2 CURSOR 
  WITH HOLD 
  WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
  with contract (Province, Con_Contract_date) as (values 
    ('Ontario', date('2017-06-11'))
  , ('Quebec', date('2017-07-12'))
  )
  SELECT province
  FROM (
  SELECT 
      contract.province,
      contract.con_contract_date
  FROM contract
  WHERE contract.CON_CONTRACT_DATE >='2015-01-01' 
  AND contract.CON_CONTRACT_DATE < '2018-11-01'
  );

  OPEN C2;
end@

CALL TEST@
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks!!